# How to output new lines in javascript using jsfiddle?

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

I am trying to learn basic javascript and using [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) as my tool of choice to play around with code. I've found I really learn through working examples I can see output for.

However, I find when I do something along the lines of the following, both lines are displayed on the same line:

```
document.writeln("This is Line One");
document.writeln("This is Line Two");
```

i.e. http://jsfiddle.net/u1sonderzug/NVSsy/

I understand as a beginner I might be going about doing this in the completely wrong way, so I'd like to understand best practices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In html, `<br>` is for new lines.

```
document.writeln("This is Line One<br>");
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not an issue of Javascript but an issue of HTML : println adds a carriage return at the end of the text but it has no effect in HTML because html doesn't take care of those characters. So you have to to :

```
writeln("....<br/>");
```

where 
 is the html tag for carriage return;

OR

```
<pre>
writeln("...");
</pre>
```

*if your javascript is wrotten in the html page. Where  is a balise to say to html he has to read every character including the carriage return added by writeln.

Anyway you should try to find tutorials for html and DOM, it's far more powerfull that this println and it's standard :)